# Remove particular content (&#8250;) from last a tag in a div

Tags: jquery, text, css-selectors

I have a list with breadcrumbs that is generated like this:

```
<div class="breadcrumps"><a href="#">Link1</a>&#8250;<a href="#">Link2</a>&#8250;<a href="#">Link3</a>&#8250;</div>
```

How can I remove the '›' after the last a tag? Currently I have this code which doesn't work...:(

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.breadcrumps');
$(this).find('a:last-child').remove('&#8250;');
```

});

thanks in advance!

Comment: `$(this)` is referring to `$(document)`. Use `$('.breadcrumps').find('a:last-child').remove('&#8250;');

Comment: If possible, when generating the breadcrumb list, don't append the &#8250; to the last element.

Comment: you spelled breadcrumbs wrong inside of your HTML. you have it as breadcrumps

Comment: @ImportedNoob he spelled it wrong consistently, which is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use substr:

```
$('.breadcrumps').text(function(x,i){return i.substr(0,i.length-1);});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XxDfY/2/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

http://jsfiddle.net/jXBte/

```
<div class="breadcrumps">
    <a href="#">Link1</a><span>&#8250;</span>
    <a href="#">Link2</a><span>&#8250;</span>
    <a href="#">Link3</a><span>&#8250;</span>
</div>
```

and the js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.breadcrumps').find('span:last-child').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.breadcrumps').html(function(index, oldHtml) {
        $(this).html(oldHtml.substring(0, oldHtml.length - 1));
    });
});
```

Just beware that the DOM elements are being replaced, so old bindings might be lost.

For example,

The following won't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        alert('Clicked');
    });

    $('.breadcrumps').html(function(index, oldHtml) {
        $(this).html(oldHtml.substring(0, oldHtml.length - 1));
    });
});
```

But this will:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.breadcrumps').html(function(index, oldHtml) {
        $(this).html(oldHtml.substring(0, oldHtml.length - 1));

        $('a').click(function() {
            alert('Clicked');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: That just removes the last character.